# Input type file as prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a browse button, I'm trying to pass to a child component ( `<attachment />` component) the browsed file but for some reason the `<AttachedFile />` component always gets the props as `{}`, what am I missing?

`Attachment` page:

```
export default class Attachment extends React.Component {
  state = {
    attachment: {},
  };

  handleAddAttachment = file => {
    this.setState({ attachment: file });
    this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);
  };

  render() {
    const { attachment } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
          <div>
            Do you have
            <br />
            something to <LineBreak />
            show me?
          </div>
          <div css={attach}>Upload attachments here</div>
          <AttachmentButton  handleAddAttachment={this.handleAddAttachment} />
          <AttachedFile attachment={attachment} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

`AttachmentButton` Component:

```
export default function AttachmentButton({ styles, handleAddAttachment }) {
  const handleUpload = file => {
    handleAddAttachment(file);
  };
  return (
    <div css={styles}>
      <div css={attachmentBox}>
        <label css={customSelectButton}>
          <input type="file" css={selectButton} onChange={e => handleUpload(e.target.files[0])} />
          Select file
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`AttachedFile` Component:

```
export default function AttachedFile({ attachment }) {
  console.log(attachment);
  return (
      <NavLink to="./" css={text}>
        {attachment.name}
      </NavLink>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not calling `handleAddAttachment`. So the attachment is always `{}`.

Comment: sorry, deleted it on the question by mistake, I just updated my question.

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth, thanks to your sandbox I noticed that what causes the issue is this line that I originally removed from the question to avoid confusions `this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);`, I'm updating a parent component with the attached file.

Comment: Do you have any idea why `this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);` avoid it to work?

Comment: @user3378165 it should also work if the `handleChange` function accepts arguments in the way you are passing them.